# Constipation during cold weather

Tags: gastroenterology, triggers, weather, constipation, air-temperature

I'm a Male late twenties living in the tropics. Over the past couple of years I get very bad constipation during the cold season. Drinking more water / fibre doesn't seem to help much.

What is the relationship between the weather and constipation. Exactly what is it about the cold that triggers constipation ?

Comment: Hi! Did you by chance have a change in diet, exercise, use certain medications only in the winter?